# Android background music service

Tags: android, android-service, background-music, android-music-player

I am developing an entertainment app in android. I want to play background music, and I want to use service for that. App have 3 activities and music must be played across all activities. Also, when activity is paused, music must PAUSE and stopped when destroyed. Can anyone tell me how to do this ? any links or examples ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**Do it without service**

https://web.archive.org/web/20181116173307/http://www.rbgrn.net/content/307-light-racer-20-days-61-64-completion

If you are so serious about **doing it with services** using mediaplayer

```
Intent svc=new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
startService(svc);
```

---

```
public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = null;
    MediaPlayer player;
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.idil);
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(100,100);

    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return 1;
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TO DO
    }
    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TO DO Auto-generated method
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {

    }
    public void onPause() {

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {

    }
}
```

Please call this **service in Manifest** 
Make sure there is no space at the end of the .BackgroundSoundService string

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".BackgroundSoundService" />
```

Comment: Why you didnt prefer service which is to control. ?

Comment: thank you! works fine but I have a problem with this code.in my application I have many activities but I have declared finish() in onPause(). I want to play bgm while going through intents but intent calls onpause and service stops(cz finish method in onpause method).do you have any solution?

Comment: This answer is correct, however you are forgetting that you also need to define the `Service` in the Manifest for it to actually work. Please see my additional answer below on how to do this.

Comment: Can someone please help me on how to pause the music using the service approach? For instance, if I press back button to go to previous activity, the music restarts instead of continuing where it left off.

Comment: How can i stop the service from another activity than the one i created it?

Comment: @AndreasKonstantakos use AudioManager [info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24476972/577046) | [info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16252044/577046)

Comment: Your link is not working anymore but here is almost the same solution https://github.com/44maagnum/princetron_android/blob/master/src/princeTron/UserInterface/MusicManager.java

Comment: what is `idil` in here?

Comment: Hey this helped a lot , and i managed to add Broadcast receiver to communicate from Activity to service, But i want to know that Is player is playing audio or not. Like if its playing display Pause button on every activity that have access to this service.. And vice versa for Play button any Idea?

Answer (score 18):

way too late for the party here but i will still add my $0.02, Google has released a free sample called universal music player with which you can learn to stream music across all android platforms(auto, watch,mobile,tv..) it uses service to play music in the background, do check it out very helpful. here's the link to the project
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer

Answer (score 9):

@Synxmax's answer is correct when using a `Service` and the `MediaPlayer` class, however you also need to declare the `Service` in the Manifest for this to work, like so:

```
<service
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name="com.package.name.BackgroundSoundService" />
```

Answer (score 6):

i had problem to run it and i make some changes to run it with mp3 source. here is `BackfrounSoundService.java` file. consider that my mp3 file is in my sdcard in my phone .

```
public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = null;
    MediaPlayer player;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("service", "onCreate");
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            player.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/your file.mp3");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(100, 100);

    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("service", "onStartCommand");
        try {
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TO DO
    }

    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TO DO Auto-generated method
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {

    }

    public void onPause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Theres an excellent tutorial on this subject at [HelloAndroid](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-ii) regarding this very subject. Infact it was the first hit i got on google. You should try googling before asking here, as it is good practice.

Answer (score 4):

Create a foreground service with the `START_STICKY` flag.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent startIntent, int flags, int startId) {
   if (startIntent != null) {
       String action = startIntent.getAction();
       String command = startIntent.getStringExtra(CMD_NAME);
       if (ACTION_CMD.equals(action)) {
           if (CMD_PAUSE.equals(command)) {
               if (mPlayback != null && mPlayback.isPlaying()) {
                   handlePauseRequest();
               }
           } else if (CMD_PLAY.equals(command)) {
               ArrayList<Track> queue = new ArrayList<>();
               for (Parcelable input : startIntent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(ARG_QUEUE)) {
                   queue.add((Track) Parcels.unwrap(input));
               }
               int index = startIntent.getIntExtra(ARG_INDEX, 0);
               playWithQueue(queue, index);
           }
       }
   }

   return START_STICKY;
}
```

This can then be called from any activity to play some music

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_CMD, fileUrlToPlay, activity, MusicService::class.java)
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(MusicService.ARG_QUEUE, tracks)
intent.putExtra(MusicService.ARG_INDEX, position)
intent.putExtra(MusicService.CMD_NAME, MusicService.CMD_PLAY)
activity.startService(intent)
```

You can bind to the service using [bindService](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binding) and to make the Service pause/stop from the corresponding activity lifecycle methods.

Here's a good tutorial about [Playing music in the background on Android](http://sapandiwakar.in/building-a-music-player-app-for-android-2/)

Answer (score 2):

I have found two great resources to share, if anyone else come across this thread via Google, this may help them ( 2018 ).
One is this video tutorial in which you'll see practically how service works, this is good for starters.

Link :-  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2ffzsCqrs8

Other is this website which will really help you with background audio player.

Link :-  https://www.dev2qa.com/android-play-audio-file-in-background-service-example/

Good Luck :)