# Android Mediaplayer should release previous song onCreate activity again

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am in learning process of the Android app development, and trying to create one songs app.

*Problem:*

I have two activities, *A:songslist* & *B:MediaPlayer*

B plays remote song via `mp.prepareAsync();` and starts player when its ready.

I want to keep running the song even though I move to other activities or if I open any other app.

But problem comes, when song is running and I go back to select new song, then oncreate activity B it starts streaming and playing new song, since old song is still running.

My Code:

```
public void Play() {
if(mp.isPlaying())
{   
 releaseMediaPlayer();
 Log.d("MediaPlayer", "Player is already running release it first");
}

mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
URL = BASE_URL + album_files[songIndex];
mp.setDataSource(URL);
mp.prepareAsync();

btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
songTitleLabel.setText("Loading track, please wait....");

}
private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (mp != null) {
        if(mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
        }
        Log.d("MediaPlayer", "Player is released");

        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a service for playing music beside playlists and mediaplayer activities. service plays the music even if you exit program and you can have a widget to control playing music.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209858/android-background-music-service). Using the answer you can make a background service and also with out background service. 
Good luck