# How to play music in the background through out the App continuously?

Tags: android, android-music-player

I have 4 activities in my android app.When the first activity is created, it starts  music in the background. Now when the user goes from 1st activity to the 2nd activity I want the song to continue without any interruption. The song should stop only when the user is out of the app.

Right now the music stops when I am going out of one activity and starts from the beginning in the next activity.

Comment: I would use a local bound service: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: then you must implement a `Service` and control the `MediaPlayer` instance from there

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android background music service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209858/android-background-music-service)

Comment: @KenWolf I don't think you should use the bindService. It will be destroyed when you unbind from it. You could better use startService (and then bind to it).

Comment: @RvdK Technically it would still be a bound service because you are binding to it and calling the public methods. You just haven't started it via the bind. But I agree with you :)

Comment: Indeed, for a real music app, the best would be not bind as it would mean the service would be in the same process as the app, which would be heavy. Having a process with the service only would be better, then interacting with it could be done via intents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the player in the background as a static reference. Then let it know if you are moving within the app or out of it. Here is how I would do it. I am using a class named DJ for this purpose.

```
public class DJ { 
private static MediaPlayer player;
private static boolean keepMusicOn;

public static void iAmIn(Context context){
if (player == null){
player = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.music1);
player.setLooping(true);

try{
player.prepare();
}
catch (IllegalStateException e){}
catch (IOException e){}
}

if(!player.isPlaying()){
player.start();
}

keepMusicOn= false;
}

public static void keepMusicOn(){
keepMusicOn= true;
}

public static void iAmLeaving(){

if(!keepMusicOn){
player.pause();
}
}
}
```

Now from your Activity call the DJ like this.(Let him know if you would like to keep the music on)

```
public void onPause() {
super.onPause();
DJ.iAmLeaving();
}

public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
DJ.iAmIn(this); 
}

public void buttonOnClick(View view){
DJ.keepMusicOn();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TheOtherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did it this way and I'm pleased with the result:

**1st create the service:**

```
public class LocalService extends Service
{
    // This is the object that receives interactions from clients. See RemoteService for a more complete example.
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private MediaPlayer player;

    /**
     * Class for clients to access. Because we know this service always runs in
     * the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder
    {
        LocalService getService()
        {
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly stopped, so return sticky.
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        destroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return mBinder;
    }


    public void play(int res)
    {
        try
        {
            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, res);
            player.setLooping(true);
            player.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
            player.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void pause()
    {
        if(null != player && player.isPlaying())
        {
            player.pause();
            player.seekTo(0);
        }
    }


    public void resume()
    {
        try
        {
            if(null != player && !player.isPlaying())
            {
                player.start();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void destroy()
    {
        if(null != player)
        {
            if(player.isPlaying())
            {
                player.stop();
            }

            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    }

}
```

**2nd**, create a base activity and extend all your activities in witch you wish to play the background music from it:

```
public class ActivityBase extends Activity
{
    private Context context = ActivityBase.this;
    private final int [] background_sound = { R.raw.azilum_2, R.raw.bg_sound_5 };
    private LocalService mBoundService;
    private boolean mIsBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        doBindService();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        try
        {
            if(null != mBoundService)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                int what = background_sound[rand.nextInt(background_sound.length)];
                mBoundService.play(what);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        basePause();
    }



    protected void baseResume()
    {
        try
        {
            if(null != mBoundService)
            {
                mBoundService.resume();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    protected void basePause()
    {
        try
        {
            if(null != mBoundService)
            {
                mBoundService.pause();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection()
    {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service)
        {
            // This is called when the connection with the service has been
            // established, giving us the service object we can use to
            // interact with the service. Because we have bound to a explicit
            // service that we know is running in our own process, we can
            // cast its IBinder to a concrete class and directly access it.
            mBoundService = ((LocalService.LocalBinder) service).getService();

            if(null != mBoundService)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                int what = background_sound[rand.nextInt(background_sound.length)];
                mBoundService.play(what);
            }
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className)
        {
            // This is called when the connection with the service has been
            // unexpectedly disconnected -- that is, its process crashed.
            // Because it is running in our same process, we should never
            // see this happen.
            mBoundService = null;

            if(null != mBoundService)
            {
                mBoundService.destroy();
            }
        }
    };

    private void doBindService()
    {
        // Establish a connection with the service. We use an explicit
        // class name because we want a specific service implementation that
        // we know will be running in our own process (and thus won't be
        // supporting component replacement by other applications).

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocalService.class);
        bindService(i, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mIsBound = true;
    }

    private void doUnbindService()
    {
        if (mIsBound)
        {
            // Detach our existing connection.
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mIsBound = false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        doUnbindService();
    }
}
```

And that's it, now you have background sound in all the activities that are extended from ActivityBase.

You can even control the pause / resume functionality by calling basePause() / baseResume().

Don't forget to declare the service in manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.gga.screaming.speech.LocalService" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you should not play music from the activity itself. On Android, Activities, and other contexts, have life cycles. It means they will live...and die. And when dead, they can't do anything any more.

So you gotta find something with a lifecycle that lasts more than a single activity if you want the music to live longer.

The easiest solution is an Android service. You can find a good thread here : [Android background music service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8209858/693752)