# How to pause audioplayer when other app need audio

Tags: android

How to pause the audio player when I launch the radio app that I develop?

And "vice-versa" , How to pause my app when the user launch the audioplayer when my app is running in background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You App needs to request the Audio-Focus, more about that [here](https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html). Once you no longer need it you can abandon the focus, which returns it to the Application which had it previously to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OnAudioFocusChangeListener` to detect if there are other apps requesting audio focus; if so, pause your audio player.

```
am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
afChangeListener = new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT){
            // Pause playback
        } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
            // Resume playback 
        } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
            abandonAudioFocus();
        }
    }
};
```

Similar SO question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474929/stop-mediaplayer-when-an-other-app-play-music)