# Pause all the other media players and audios while Application media player starts playing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am working on a push to talk App, where the receiver will get a live-streamed audio message from a sender if he is connected to the internet. Now everything's working all fine except one issue that is: whenever any other applications like google music or youtube are playing audios, that time if I am getting an audio notification or message through the application, both the audios are playing in a parallel manner. I am using VoiceLayer library for the app and to play a message audio, they use VoiceLayerMessagePlayer. Is there any way I can pause the other media players when I am getting a notification or voice message in my Application? I looked through the internet and found out that OnAudioFocusChangeListener might be helpful but didn't get a proper example regarding its implementation. Please do let me know if you need any more information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"Is there anyway I can pause the other media players"_ No. You can _ask_ them to pause by requesting audio focus, but you can't _force_ them to pause.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for your reply. Can you please elaborate a little about requesting audio focus.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus.html

Comment: @Michael: Thank you. Let me have a look then.

Answer (score 0):

You should use AudioManager service to receive notification whether you receive/lost audio focus (Managing audio focus). I've done similar thing in a project where when my app starts playing, Google Play pause and vice versa. Use the following code where you are controlling your media playback like (activity or service)

[Stop MediaPlayer when an other app play music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474929/stop-mediaplayer-when-an-other-app-play-music)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code it's working fine.

```
AudioManager am = null;

// Request focus for music stream and pass 
AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener
// implementation reference
int result = am.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

if(result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED)
{
    // Play
}

// Implements AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener

@Override
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) 
{
    if(focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT)
    {
        // Pause
    }
    else if(focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
    {
        // Resume
    }
    else if(focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS)
    {
        // Stop or pause depending on your need
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you and solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

please try this code. it work with me

```
  val audioManager = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
  val focusRequest = AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN).run {
        setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes.Builder().run {
            setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
            setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            setOnAudioFocusChangeListener({  }, object : Handler() {})
            build()
        })
        setAcceptsDelayedFocusGain(true)
        build()
    }
    audioManager.requestAudioFocus(focusRequest)
```