# How can I stop youtube music?

Tags: java, android

I am using **AudioManager** in order to make this work.

**This is what I have done:**

```
private AudioManager isPlaying = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if(isPlaying.isMusicActive()) {
    isPlaying.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
} else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "There is no music playing..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I want to stop the music playing from youtube or any other app. In addition, how can I pause it and resume it?

Comment: perhaps this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474929/stop-mediaplayer-when-an-other-app-play-music

Answer (score 0):

In [Stop MediaPlayer when an other app play music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474929/stop-mediaplayer-when-an-other-app-play-music)

A person answer

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if(manager.isMusicActive())
 {
     // do something - or don't
 }
```