# Playing a song while app is running

Tags: android, eclipse, audio-player

I want to play a song on "raw" folder across my application is running until its finished. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can start the song in background and make it run across your entire app using a service.
Later, you can stop the song in onDestroy() method of your launcher activity.

This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8209975/3970830