# Play video when app goes background android

Tags: android, video, streaming, playback, video-player

How to keep continue playing video when we press Home button and app go to background? At that time we still able to listen to the audio and work on another app. 
Should we add service to control video playing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209858/android-background-music-service solution here

Comment: @weijingwan He want to continue playing video, not just audio.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is running in background, the only way to show something to screen (image, `View` objects) is using `WindowManager` in `Service`. 
You should create a `Service`, then add the `View` you want to show to the `WindowManager`.

I'm not sure that you can show your video with `WindowManager`. But I think it is the only way to try.

Comment: I just wanna play audio only. Should I start service when start playing video or just start service when activity goes background?