# Adding Multiple songs in a Service

Tags: android, service, media-player

Im creating an app that requires Multiple songs to play in the background
i have understood the looping feature in a previous question.

[Android background music service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209858/android-background-music-service)

but the service plays only one song.

how can i add multiple songs to the service and have them play full length