# Why mediaPlayer plays 15 minutes and then stop?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

when I lock my Android Screen,my app is still playing music(it means the mediaPlayer is working),but after 15 minutes,the music will be stoped,dou you know why?

(I did not use Service or  BindService at all,just Use MediaPlayer Class)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it happens, why? 
because I think you are using `MediaPlayer` in `Activity`, and android release some untouched resources after some time to give space to other processes.

you have to use foreground Service to prevent this problem.

Here is example of MediaPlayer inside Service.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8209975/6676466

Comment: haha, No, I don't know mandarin. We can not chat on comments, Please take care of this. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Release the player memory by using [onDestroy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) method

```
@Override
   public void onDestroy() {
       if (mp!= null) mp.release();
   }
```