# How can I make my Android WebView play music or audio in the background with an audio player in the status bar? Here is my MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, audio, webview

```
package net.socialkit.socialkitandroidwebview;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdvancedWebView.Listener
{
    private AdvancedWebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.socialkitWebView);
        mWebView.setListener(this, this);
        mWebView.loadUrl(getString(R.string.url));
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mWebView.onResume();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        mWebView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        mWebView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        mWebView.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if (!mWebView.onBackPressed()) { return; }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(String url, Bitmap favicon) { }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(String url) { }

    @Override
    public void onPageError(int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) { }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadRequested(String url, String suggestedFilename, String mimeType, long contentLength, String contentDisposition, String userAgent) { }

    @Override
    public void onExternalPageRequest(String url) { }
}
```

How can I make my Android WebView play music or audio in the background with an audio player in the status bar? Here is my MainActivity.java

I need to solve this problem, to be able to play sound or audio in the background if I have to be with the application open, and if it can, with a music player in the status bar

Comment: what is the problem with your above posted code ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209858/android-background-music-service

Comment: I need you to play the music or audio without having the application open (background), and if you can with a mini player in the status bar