# How to pause and resume background music when pressing back button or pressing the home button.

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8209975/3938789) answer which uses service class to create play background music for all activities in the app.

The problem I have is that when a user presses back button to go to previous activity, or clicks on  home button, or recent apps button and relaunches the app, the music starts all over again. I want the music to resume where it left off.

The music should start over ONLY when the user exits the app via the exit button that I have in my app.

So here's what I have done in my onPause and onResume methods:

```
@Override
    protected void onPause(){

        super.onPause();

        if (!this.isFinishing()){
            Intent svc=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BackgroundSoundService.class);
            stopService(svc);
        }
}



@Override
    protected void onResume(){

        super.onResume();

        Intent svc=new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
        startService(svc);

    }
```

These two methods are there in every activity.

Also, to start the music, I used the following code in the MainActivity (Launcher Activity) of my class:

```
 Intent svc=new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
    startService(svc);
```

If you look at the **onPause()** method, you will see that I used **stopService()** method to stop the music. I could not find **pauseService()** or something similar to pause the music. Can anyone help me on this one?