# How to start a service in Oncreate without button Onclick ,but it should be stopped using button

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-lifecycle

I am trying to play music continuously in background without any button click,it should play on launching activity,and again it can be stopped by stop button.But it is not stopping as it is placed in Oncreate() ,what can be the solution for this.
Please anyone tell me how to stopservice.Thankyou in advance.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    start = findViewById(R.id.startbutton);
    stop = findViewById(R.id.stopbutton);


    Intent i = new Intent(this, Service.class);
    this.startService(i);
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), Service.class);
            stopService(i);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "stop service called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), Service.class);
            startService(i);
        }
    });

}
```

Below is my Service code

```
private MediaPlayer player;
public Service() {
    super();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  player= MediaPlayer.create(this,
          Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
  player.setLooping(true);
  player.start();
  return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    player.stop();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: can you update your question with `ESS_Service` where you start and stop the music?

Comment: Post the Service code also... and try to use Activity context..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android background music service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209858/android-background-music-service)

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this,I can play music when app is launched without clicking button,and can also stop it by clicklistener,but after destroying and reopening the app ,not able to stop service.

Answer (score 1):

Please Add this override method and call what ever service you need.

```
@Override
 public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  startService(new Intent(YourActivity.this, ServiceName.class));
}
```

Comment: Service is getting called,but it is not stopping by clicklistener when I close the app and reopen.

Comment: in onDestroy you can stopservice, and also in clicklistener of stop view using stopSelf().

Answer (score 0):

I have thought of two solutions :

1:Just don't use clicklistener . Immediately start the service when launching the activity

2: If you want to use start button , call `start.performClick()`

To stop the player on home screen use this method

```
    @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    player.stop();
}
```

Comment: Yeah I am starting service immediately without clicklistener,but how can I stop service on clicklistener,that is my question.

Comment: write the `stop.setOnClickListener` code outside onCreate and try

Comment: If still not  working try writing the code in `onStart` or `onResume`

Comment: I tried both ,still stop service is not working after closing and reopening app

Comment: Have you declared the service in AndroidManifest.xml. `<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".Service" />`

Comment: you are calling `player.stop` in `onDestroy` which is only called when you remove the app from the recent apps stack from your mobile

Comment: I have added a code in my answer try it and tell me what happens

Comment: There is no onPause method in Android service lifecycle.So I am not able to add it.

Comment: Try to add onPause it in MainActivity class

Comment: I have tried it in onPause and in all lifecycle methods in MainActivity class.

Answer (score 0):

I am returning START_NOT_STICKY in onStartCommand method in Service class instead of START_STICKY.Because of that my service was restarting every time when I reopen the app.So now I am able to stop service and my problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.stopService(i);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    this.startService(i);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    start = findViewById(R.id.startbutton);
    stop = findViewById(R.id.stopbutton);


     i = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
    this.startService(i);
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(i!=null) {
                stopService(i);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "stop service called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: Make intent a class variable and override onPause and onResume. That should do the trick. As mentioned by Harish Reddy.