# game background music

Tags: java, android

Hello im making a android game application and i want to make a background music for my game. i have found some code here in stackoverflow but its not work properly because when i press the back button or home button the music is still playing, even i remove it from task its still running it mean onPause or onDestroy is not working. can someone help me, thank you!.

here's the link where i found the codes
[Android background music service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209858/android-background-music-service)

Comment: You really don't want to use a service for that.

Comment: ohh okay so how do i play a background music for my game? that plays all my activities

Comment: Maybe, don't use a bunch of Activities, just one. And swap Fragments inside it. Which is a *best practice*.

Comment: i used activities for intent my app game.

Comment: Bad choice, actually.

Comment: any idea for background music??

Comment: *Not* using a service. But you'd have to rethink ALL your app, so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) First put your music.mp3 into raw folder

2) Declaring a service in the manifest as child of the `<application>` element

```
<service android:name=".SoundService"  android:enabled="true"/>
```

3) Add `MusicService.java` class:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class SoundService extends Service {

MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music); 
        mPlayer.setLooping(true); 
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mPlayer.start();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

4) Run\Stop services in the activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SoundService.class));

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SoundService.class));
        super.onBackPressed();    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // When the app is going to the background
        stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SoundService.class)); 
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // when system temporarily destroying activity 
        stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SoundService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, but when i pressed home button its still playing

Comment: It's still playing, because it's a *service*.

Comment: my setvolume is not working, how do i reduce my sound volume

Answer (score 0):

I think you play music as a service and you must destroy this service in onPause and onDestroy of your activity.