# Push notification sound is not playing app is in background

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-push-notification

when i am sending notification from firebase at that time when app is background then notification comes but notification sound is not play. but when app is running at that time sound is playing.
And there is problem when i am sending notification to lower version app is closed please let me know is there any other solution here is my code

this is my broadcast receiver

```
 mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)) {
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Config.TOPIC_GLOBAL);
                } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {


                    pendingListAdapter = new PendingListAdapter(MainActivity.this, getPendingList(str_society_id, str_staff_id));
                    Functions.setDatatoRecyclerView(rv_pendings, pendingListAdapter, MainActivity.this);
                    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        int importance = mNotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(Config.CHANNEL_ID, Config.CHANNEL_NAME, importance);
                        mChannel.setDescription(Config.CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION);
                        mChannel.enableLights(true);
                        mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
                        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(MainActivity.this, soundUri);
                        r.play();
                        mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});


                        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
                        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(MainActivity.this);
                        notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();

                        MyNotificationManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).displayNotification("Greetings", message);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Push notification: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                                .setContentTitle("Greetings")
                                .setContentText(message)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_app)
                                .setAutoCancel(true)

                                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC).build();
                        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
                        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(MainActivity.this);
                        notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();


                    }

                    notification_count = sharedPreferencesDatabase.getData(Config.NOTIFICATION_COUNT);
                    int i_notification_count = 0;
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(notification_count) && !TextUtils.equals(notification_count, "null")) {
                        i_notification_count = Integer.parseInt(notification_count);
                    }

                    i_notification_count = i_notification_count + 1;
                    sharedPreferencesDatabase.addData(Config.NOTIFICATION_COUNT, "" + i_notification_count);

                    if (i_notification_count != 0) {
                        tv_notification_count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tv_notification_count.setText("" + i_notification_count);
                    } else {
                        tv_notification_count.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

this is my firebase FirebaseInstanceIdService

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        storeRegIdInPref(refreshedToken);

        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);

        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        registrationComplete.putExtra("token", refreshedToken);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(final String token) {
        // sending gcm token to server
        Log.e(TAG, "sendRegistrationToServer: " + token);
    }

    private void storeRegIdInPref(String token) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREFERENCE_DB_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("regId", token);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

this is my FirebaseMessagingService

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

    private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage == null)
            return;

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

            handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        }

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                handleDataMessage(json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleNotification(String message) {
        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        } else {


            // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
        }
    }

    private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
        Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

        try {
            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

            String title = data.getString("title");
            String message = data.getString("message");
            boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
            String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
            String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
            JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

            Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
            Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
            Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
            Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
            Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
            Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);


            if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
                // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
                Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

                // play notification sound
                NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
                notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
            } else {
                // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

                // check for image attachment
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                    showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
                } else {
                    // image is present, show notification with image
                    showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text only
     */
    private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text and image
     */
    private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To Play an audio from your application when your app is in background you have to use Services. Check out this link : [Android background music service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209858/android-background-music-service)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling sound from console? Have a look

[image]