# I'm developing music player app that runs music on the background service and when I leave the app media player stops

Tags: java, android, service

I'm developing music player app that runs music on the background service and when I leave the app media player stops.
This is my code when I leave the app media player mustn't be playing.
class MusicService extends Service{

```
private  MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

private void initPlayer(){
    if (mediaPlayer==null){
        mediaPlayer =new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this,Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent!=null && intent.getAction()!=null && intent.getAction().equals("com.play")){
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to keep playing the music in the background after leaving the app, update the manifest too:

[Android background music service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209858/android-background-music-service)

as this post describes.

Comment: the media player stops when i leave the app