# How do i keep same song playing in all activities

Tags: java, android

i'm creating an android application and i need to keep one song playing even if i went to another Activity.
Help me please, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in two ways, using the [singleton pattern](https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-to-make-the-perfect-singleton-de6b951dfdb0) or using a [background service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209858/android-background-music-service) (recommended)

Answer (score 1):

Use a service, but it has to be a foreground service so that it has the highest priority so that it doesn't lag nor is killed by the system on low memory, follow this example:
https://www.dev2qa.com/android-foreground-service-example/